# TextViews Gravity does not work vertically

Tags: android, canvas, textview, gravity, drawingcache

when i draw the DrawingCache of a TextView to another View's Canvas, the Gravity of the TextView has no effect in vertical direction.

Here the class drawing the TextViews canvas to own canvas:

```
public class GravityDecorator extends View{
    private View view;
    private Paint paint= new Paint();

    public GravityDecorator(View view,Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.view = view;
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.layout(0, 0,600,500);
        this.layout(0, 0,600,500);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        view.buildDrawingCache();       
        canvas.drawBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, paint);     
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
    }

}
```

Here is the code to test it (onCreate):

```
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root); // is a linear_layout - width and height is match_parent
    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tv.setText("Hello World!");
    tv.setTextSize(40.0f);      
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,200));     
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3131c5"));
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    GravityDecorator gd = new GravityDecorator(tv, getApplicationContext());
    root.addView(gd);
```

As you see, the Gravity of the TextViews content only takes effect in the horizontal direction.

What is the reason and how to work around this, if its a bug ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root); // is a linear_layout - width and height is match_parent
tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
tv.setText("Hello World!");
tv.setTextSize(40.0f);      
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,200));     
tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3131c5"));
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tv.invalidate();
root.addView(tv);
GravityDecorator gd = new GravityDecorator(tv, getApplicationContext());
root.addView(gd);
```

Might be because the layout param is not getting set for the `TextView` Initially. Try to add the view to the Parent and then get the `drawingCache`.

```
public class GravityDecorator extends View{
    private View view;
    private Paint paint= new Paint();

    public GravityDecorator(View view,Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.view = view;
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.layout(0, 0,600,500);
        this.layout(0, 0,600,500);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        view.buildDrawingCache();      

        Bitmap bmp = view.getDrawingCache();

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);     
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        if(root.indexOfChild(tv) != -1)
            root.removeView(tv);


    }

}
```

Comment: This will draw the content of the TextView in center, but the Size is like "wrap_content" now. I want to implement a class, which decorates every view with a border (top, left, right, bottom - or rounded). So this class here is just example to demonstrate the behavior without all the other code. My class to decorate the views with a border works, including padding and margin - but the gravity not.

Comment: The bitmap you are getting is the exact same height what you are providing inside layout params     tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,200));

Comment: oh, ok. i missed that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there another option instead of adding and removing the view ?